# Unknown command beginning SELECT ... Error?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database

I'm trying to run the following command in Oracle

```
SELECT artistic_name 
FROM Artist 
INNER JOIN Groups ON artistic_name = Groups.group_name, Groups.group_name = ‘Frankensense’, OR Groups.group_name = ‘Jameson’;
```

The error is: `SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "1) SELECT ..." - rest of line ignored.`

I can't see what the exact problem is with this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you really prefix the SQL statement with the string `1) `?  The error message seems to indicate that this was an explicit part of the SQL statement you are trying to execute rather than being mere formatting here in your post.

Comment: @JustinCave no I did not, I just copied the 1) by accident.

Comment: OK.  Then please edit your question so that you are trying to execute the actual SQL statement you have posted above and post the error that executing that particular SQL statement generates.

Comment: Apart from the obvious syntax error you are also using the wrong qutoes. SQL uses `'`, those that you are using `‘`,`’`  are invalid quotes in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, posting the exact error (the ORA-xxxxx error code and the full text of the error message) is always helpful.

I suspect that you want

```
SELECT artistic_name 
  FROM Artist 
       INNER JOIN Groups 
       ON artistic_name = Groups.group_name
 WHERE Groups.group_name IN ('Frankensense', 'Jameson');
```

You could also put the `group_name` predicate in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT artistic_name 
  FROM Artist 
       INNER JOIN Groups 
       ON(     artistic_name = Groups.group_name
           AND Groups.group_name IN ('Frankensense', 'Jameson'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell us the error. In the meantime, remove the extra commas.

```
SELECT artistic_name 
FROM Artist
INNER JOIN Groups
  ON artistic_name = Groups.group_name
    AND Groups.group_name = 'Frankensense'
    OR Groups.group_name = 'Jameson';
```

You might want to add parentheses depending on how you want the at "ON" clause to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
SELECT artistic_name 
FROM Artist 
INNER JOIN Groups ON artistic_name = Groups.group_name 
  AND (Groups.group_name = 'Frankensense' OR Groups.group_name = 'Jameson')
```

No commas are needed for `JOIN` or `WHERE` conditions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you meant to have a WHERE clause, and remove the commas:

```
 SELECT artistic_name 
 FROM Artist 
   INNER JOIN Groups ON artistic_name = Groups.group_name 
 WHERE Groups.group_name = 'Frankensense' 
    OR Groups.group_name = 'Jameson';
```